# upgradation of alfresco 4.2.2 to 5.x

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Presently our application has been deployed in Alfresco 4.2.2 Enterprise version.We want to move our application to 5.x Alfresco version.

What are all versions released so far in 5.x?Initially I want to test our application in all 5.x Community Versions that are released so far.Where can we download old & new 5.x Community Versions?

What are the new features added in 5.x w.r.t 4.2.2?

Comment: Lucene/SOLR, be aware that the default search in 5.x is SOLR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the community versions here : https://sourceforge.net/projects/alfresco/files/

The current enteprise version is the 5.1. The previous version was 5.0.3.

About the new features, I encourage you to look at the different [releases notes](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/whats-new.html) because I don't know what you are looking for.

The biggest change for me is the disappearance of the alfresco legacy backend, the end of lucene and the refactoring of some apis.

Comment: wat is Alfresco 201605 Community,Alfresco 201512-EA Community,Alfresco 5.0.d Community.Alfresco 5.0.c Community,Alfresco 5.0.b Community??

Comment: I would say that there are different version of community names but I think this is not the answer you want. Historically, versions of community alfresco where name with a letter at the end (4.2.e) while the enterprise version had a number (4.2.5). Now, it seems that the date has replaced the version. Keep in mind that a 4.2.a community version doesn't mean that this is the same product as 4.2.1 enteprise.

Comment: EA - early access, GA - generally available, you can Google out the naming convention.